# Can I keep my database and data from installation of Magento?

Tags: magento2, database, installation

I know tables will be created during the installation of a new Magento application.
But what if my database is not empty, will it skip this process during the installation?
I want to use old database structure and also skip any errors occurred during the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `bin/magento setup:install` command there is a flag `--cleanup-database`. According to the documents, it is used "To drop database tables before installing the Magento software, specify this parameter without a value. Otherwise, the Magento database is left intact." https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html#instgde-install-cli-magento

This should mean that if you already have a Magento database in place and do not want to remove these tables then you can leave this flag off your installation process and the existing database tables should not be dropped.

Comment: could you please check this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/313448/magento-2-2-6-disk-space-utilization-very-fast

Answer (score 0):

You can create new magento with new database and after that You can import old database dump to new one.

You can also `install` new magento and connect it to `old` database but be sure You set up env.php property (connection to old database).